# Is CMake "set(XXXX CACHE ...)" a bug when used in a library?

Tags: cmake, build, scope, global

I'm using CMake in my project, as does one of my project's third-party library (included with `add_subdirectory()` for convenience). I have been having strange build issues, and I think I've tracked them down to the following line in the third-party library's top-level `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX "d" CACHE STRING "")
```

This sets `CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX` for my entire project (except for any subtrees where it's explicitly set), which breaks my build. Worse, the build behavior is order- and time-dependent, with the value being changed in the middle of my build after a clean build, and not after a rebuild. (Lots of fun to track down.)

The library sets lots of cache variables whose name begins with "XXXX_", where "XXXX" is the name of the library. That's fine by me, as it's unlikely these variables will be used by others' code. But, it seems antisocial to set commonly-used variables globally when your code is meant to be a component of someone else's project. It also is fragile; if I use `set(XXXX <aValue>)` in my top-level `CMakeLists.txt` then the library's `set(XXXX CACHE...)` statements will be ignored.

Instead, the library should just use `set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX "d")`, which sets the variable for all of the library's code tree, and nobody else's.

Is this a bug in the library's build code? Should libraries that aim to be good CMake citizens avoid CACHE variables except for their clearly-named private variables?

Comment: Why not tell us what library is that? Notify the maintainer of that library.

Comment: "Is this a bug in the library's build code?" - For determine whether some behavior is a project's bug or not, one need to know **requirements** for the project. Most likely, the library project is not intended to work as subproject (via `add_subdirectory`). So it is not a library's bug that you use it in unsupported way.

Comment: @KamilCuk I deliberately didn't want to focus on the library itself, but on the practice. If the answer here is that "yes: it's bad practice", I'll file a pull request with them.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Very true. I've clarified my use of `add_subdirectory()` in the question. (Thanks.)

Comment: "Instead, the library should just use set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX "d"), which sets the variable for all of the library's code tree, and nobody else's."... no they should not, because then the postfix cannot be externally overridden when the project _is_ top-level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For libraries that intend to be usable as a subproject (via `add_subdirectory` or `FetchContent`), I would say it *is* a bug to set such cache variables without a check that the project is top-level. On the other hand, a project that does *not* intend to be usable this way should explicitly check and issue a fatal error (or maybe an author warning) in this case. So either way, I would argue there's a bug and you should notify the maintainers.

In CMake 3.21+ the variable `PROJECT_IS_TOP_LEVEL` works. In earlier versions, you can write:

```
string(COMPARE EQUAL "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" PROJECT_IS_TOP_LEVEL)
```

to get the same variable. Then check:

```
if (PROJECT_IS_TOP_LEVEL)
  # Either this: (AUTHOR_WARNING acceptable, too)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Subproject inclusion not supported")
  # or:
  set(CMAKE_* ... CACHE ...)
endif ()
```

Comment: It's exactly as Alex is saying. Many CMake libraries don't work nicely with add_subdirectory. Many libraries expect users to install them, and then use find_package.